# Build war with selected classes, depending on a profile

Tags: java, spring, maven, profiling, profile

I am building a `Spring` application with the use of `maven`.

In my application, I have two implementations (java classes) of one interface and want to use one of them, depending on the **profile** that I define during app building. Each of these implementations is in its separate app `maven module`. When building an application, I want to include in a `war` file only this one selected implementation.

When it comes to ***using the selected class***, I have an idea to refer to some variable (defined in the profile in the `<properties>` section) in the application so as to get to know the choice and thus - use selected implementation.

When it comes to ***including in war only the selected class***, I have no idea how should I do it. I am a beginner, have read this [introduction to profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) but still don't know how to make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use maven war plugin - include and exclude feature with regular expression. Refer below links:

1. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html
2. http://mojo.codehaus.org/license-maven-plugin/examples/update-file-header-config.html